# Запуск видео без участия пользователя

Tags: javascript, видео

Запустить видео без участия пользователя возможно, при условии что предварительно будет выключен звук.

Хорошо, с этим разобрались.

Что интересно, если пользователь переходит к просмотру другого видео на странице и при этом включен автоплей.

В данном случаи предварительно выключать звук нет необходимости. Видео запускается со звуком. Ок, возникает другой вопрос.

Так как играет видео со звуком и пользователь переходит по ссылке. Как запомнить или определить, что пользователь перешел по внутренней ссылки и необходимости предварительно выключать звук(для запуска плеера) нет.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/referrer

Comment: Ок, в таком случаи когда пользователь обновляет страницу.  К примеру через cntrl+r, не работает...

Comment: Мне вот интересно, как у ютуб все работает. Почему видео запускается со звуком даже когда пользователь впервые перешел

Comment: он тоже не всегда запускается.